How to send custom status code in Spring Boot /oauth/token API (spring version 2.5.2)
In spring boot projact, I want to handle oauth/token API. If credentials are correct, it successfully return status: 200 and other details (access token, refresh token, etc).
I created Java class Oauth2UserServiceImpl by implementing UserDetailsService. Then overrided loadUserByUsername method. Inside that, before checking the credential validity, I need to check whether this user's status is 'Active' and password expiered. The following code shows the way I'm checking it.
if (!vendorEntity.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE)) throw new LBCLServiceException(INACTIVE_ACCOUNT, "This vendor has been deactivated.");
if (vendorEntity.is_temporary_password() && new Date().after(vendorEntity.getPassword_expiration())) throw new LBCLServiceException(UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS, "Your login details have been expired.");
And this INACTIVE_ACCOUNT refers 605 status, TEMPORARY_PASSWORD_EXPIRED refers 705. My concern is, these status are not returning but always 401 returns in header.

605 and 705 are not valid HTTP statuses. Are you confusing the HTTP status with some other data item called "status" in the response body?

Hi @sbridewell, thank you for the consideration! Do you think if I set valid status such as 404, and 205 it will return the same code.?

401 seems like the correct HTTP status for these scenarios, you just need to ensure that the client code can handle HTTP status 401 and then look into the response body to find the cause of the 401 status.
